# Mac C++ in Visual studio code Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++, c, xcode, visual-studio

So I know there are a ton of other posts about this issue and I have dug through probably most looking for a solution. I am running on a Mac OS and have Xcode 10.3. I am compiling with g++ not gcc. This isn't that complicated of a project however there are multiple files in it. My module.cpp file is my main and is below. I can provide the rest of the files if necessary. Below the code is the exact error.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;
#include "expression.h"
#include "subexpression.h"
#include "symboltable.h"
#include "parse.h"

//create an object of SymbolTable
SymbolTable symbolTable;

//prototype of the function
void parseAssignments(stringstream& in);

//define main function
int main(){

    //Variables
    Expression* expression;

    char paren, comma;
    string line;

    //create input file stream
    ifstream fin("input.txt");

    //check if the file is open
    //if file is not open error message

    if(!fin.is_open())
        perror("error with opening file!");

    //create loop to read from file content
    while(getline(fin, line)){
        symbolTable.init();
        if(!fin)
            break;
        stringstream in(line, ios_base::in);
        in >> paren;
        cout << line << " ";
        expression = SubExpression::parse(in);
        in >> comma;

        //call the functiion 
        parseAssignments(in);

        //display results
        int result = expression->evaluate();
        cout << "value = " << result << endl;
    }  

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

//define parseAssignments()
void parseAssignments(stringstream& in){
    char assignop, delimiter;
    string variable;
    int value;
    symbolTable.init();
    do{
        variable = parseName(in);
        in >> ws >> assignop >> value >> delimiter;
        symbolTable.insert(variable, value);
    }

    while (delimiter == ',');
}
```

cd "/Users/Will/Desktop/Project2/" && g++ module.cpp -o module && "/Users/Will/Desktop/Project2/"module
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "parseName(std::__1::basic_stringstream, std::__1::allocator >&)", referenced from:
      parseAssignments(std::__1::basic_stringstream, std::__1::allocator >&) in module-829ab3.o
  "SymbolTable::init()", referenced from:
      _main in module-829ab3.o
      parseAssignments(std::__1::basic_stringstream, std::__1::allocator >&) in module-829ab3.o
  "SymbolTable::insert(std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >, double)", referenced from:
      parseAssignments(std::__1::basic_stringstream, std::__1::allocator >&) in module-829ab3.o
  "SubExpression::parse(std::__1::basic_stringstream, std::__1::allocator >&)", referenced from:
      _main in module-829ab3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Have you told the compiler where to find these functions like `parseName`? The compilation command doesn't suggest so, but you mentioned an XCode project, which should handle the compilation command for you.

Comment: There is indeed no definition of the function `parseName` in the code shown. Nor of `SymbolTable::init()`, or the others mentioned in the errors.

Comment: chris you are correct that the Xcode handles the compilation. But if it is because the functions are not defined in my main but are in the other files it calls. Do I still need to define them in this modules.cpp file?

Comment: If they're defined elsewhere, Xcode should be recognizing that it needs to reference that other location in order to link your executable. Are all these cpp files actually in the project? Creating the others without including them in the project would conceivably lead to the IDE ignoring the others.

Comment: All the header files and .cpp files are all in the same project. So you are saying Xcode should pick up the functions from the imported files? and I still need to reference them?

Comment: If they're in the same project, I would expect the IDE to compile all of them (e.g., `g++ -c source.cpp -o source1.o` etc.) and link the results when creating the executable (e.g., `ld -o output source1.o source2.o ...`). It's very weird to me that Xcode wouldn't do this and I'd suggest researching whether that's normal and what the conditions are for it to change its behaviour.

Comment: I am under the assumption that it is visual studio that is causing this problem.